# How to profile a LINQPad query?

Tags: profiling, linqpad

I want to determine where to optimize code in a LINQPad query. How can I do that?

Note that I'm *not* asking how to profile *LINQ queries*; just regular (C#) code in a LINQPad 'query' file (a regular LINQPad file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest is to write a Visual Studio console app. Barring that, I use a class I added to My Extensions - it is not terribly accurate in that it doesn't account for its own overhead well, but multiple loops through help:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public static class Profiler {
    static int depth = 0;
    static Dictionary<string, Stopwatch> SWs = new Dictionary<string, Stopwatch>();
    static Dictionary<string, int> depths = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    static Stack<string> names = new Stack<string>();
    static List<string> nameOrder = new List<string>();

    static Profiler() {
        Init();
    }

    public static void Init() {
        SWs.Clear();
        names.Clear();
        nameOrder.Clear();
        depth = 0;
    }

    public static void Begin(string name = "",
        [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
        [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
        [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0) {
        name += $" ({Path.GetFileName(sourceFilePath)}: {memberName}@{sourceLineNumber})";

        names.Push(name);
        if (!SWs.ContainsKey(name)) {
            SWs[name] = new Stopwatch();
            depths[name] = depth;
            nameOrder.Add(name);
        }
        SWs[name].Start();
        ++depth;
    }

    public static void End() {
        var name = names.Pop();
        SWs[name].Stop();
        --depth;
    }

    public static void EndBegin(string name = "",
        [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
        [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
        [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0) {
        End();
        Begin(name, memberName, sourceFilePath, sourceLineNumber);
    }

    public static void Dump() {
        nameOrder.Select((name, i) => new {
            Key = (new String('\t', depths[name])) + name,
            Value = SWs[name].Elapsed
        }).Dump("Profile");
    }
}
```